# How can I count total number of sales per month using a condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I searched the forum but couldn't find a problem like the one I have. I have a table called Journal Table and it has the following data:

[image: Journal Table]

A transaction is considered to be sales if the Quantity>0 otherwise it's a loan transaction. Now my question is how can I count the total number of transactions as Sales Per month.

Like:

```
Month | TotalSales
1       5
2       3
3       7
```

I tried the following but got the wrong output:

```
Select DISTINCT Month(date) AS 'Month', 
(Select COUNT(TransactionID) from journalTable where Quantity>0) 
AS 'Total Sales' from journalTable;
```

Here is a picture of the output:

[image: Wrong output as it counts total and shows it for each month]

The output is wrong as it counts the total of all months and shows it for each month. It should count each month's total and show it.

Comment: How do you get `Month = 1` with `5` `Sales` ? There isn't even a transaction dated January

Comment: Yeah I don't have data for January, that's just an example of the output I would like to have.

Comment: It is expected to show expected result that correspond to the provided sample data

Comment: Thanks, I will be careful next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `group by` and conditionally `sum`.

```
select Month(date) as 'Month'
    , sum(case when Quantity > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total Sales'
    -- You can even add a count of loans at the same time.
    , sum(case when Quantity <= 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total Loans'
from journalTable
group by Month(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
 SELECT MONTH(DATE) AS MONTH, COUNT(QUANTITY)CNTT
 FROM TRANSACTIONS
 WHERE QUANTITY > 0
 GROUP BY MONTH(DATE)
```

Comment: The issue doing it that way is that months with 0 sales get missed.